# Sharepoint Problems: Modifying Uploads?

Tags: document-library, file-upload

We've noticed that some of our files have been modified by Sharepoint when uploading - specifically HTML files.

1. Is this common / has this happened to anyone else?
2. Is it specific to only a certain type of file?

Comment: @wizlog: thank you, I didn't realize there was a Sharepoint-dedication section.  Can I migrate this or can a moderator help me with that?

Comment: Perhaps explain how they were modified?

Comment: How are determining that the files are modified? Are the contents actually changing? or is it possible that you are actually looking at the modification date in the Document library? That date is the date that the library record was changed, so it will change when you upload an item or when you change any of the meta-data and is different than the actual file modification date.

Comment: Hey all: I don't have much information on how they've been modified, other than Sharepoint has inserted some information (my guess is adjusted the HTML).  I'm unsure if the uploaded files were valid HTML (or not), but the concern was that if Sharepoint freely alters some files, how can they be sure other files won't be altered.  Perhaps I was a little premature in asking my question w/o obtaining all the facts in our own case, but I would like to know if its possible that SP alters/inserts some files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this with html files, but I know that SharePoint modifies MS Office documents. Specifically, the document library metadata is inserted into the actual document content when the document is either uploaded or the document properties are modified.

Comment: Perhaps this is what they were thinking and got confused with the file type.  Though, I think I've seen Visual Studio modify web pages when saved through it in the [distant] past; specifically, I think I went to a WYSIWYG view, didn't make any changes, but still Ctrl+S.  Does SP have a web editor that this is something they could have done?

Comment: Yes the SharePoint html editors do tend to try to reformat html when a page is being edited through the browser (often to much frustration!). Maybe this is what your users are complaining about?

Comment: Perhaps. I will try to test out all cases.  Do you know if I add a text document and include meta information with that, will it modify the text document?  I thought that data was stored in the SQL Server underlayer.

Answer (score 1):

Only a custom added component would modify uploaded content to a SharePoint Library, but it would need a damn good reason, and a very specific use-case to do so. Nearly all files are uploaded and stored verbatim, but there may sometimes (i.e. rarely) be changes in the rendered output of the file.

Comment: Thank you James.  I can't get a hold of the group that mentioned it, they only noticed it in testing.

Answer (score 0):

In 7 years with SharePoint I have never seen that.

What happens in SharePoint 2010 is that html inserted in a page - either directly or via a Web Part - might be modified. As far as I know users have no control on this.